# Reference all commits between master branch-tip and HEAD in git

Tags: git

I currently am branched out of master (call it branchA). I have made a couple of commits to branchA and would now like to squash commits together on my branch prior to merging to master. Usually I do something like this in my branchA repo:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~n
```

I would get `n` by doing a `git log` and manually counting the commits from (not including) the master branch tip until (and including) the branch's `HEAD`. For now the count has been easy as the commits are few.

Is there a simple way to reference all commits on current branch after master branch-tip commit?

Comment: HEAD is _always_ where you are. Do you mean branch tips?

Comment: In other words, there's no such thing as "master HEAD".

Comment: I see. Yes, then I mean branch tips.

Comment: I tried to update my question using better terminology.

Comment: Have you tried `git rebase -i master`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to reference all commits on current branch after master branch-tip commit?

Yes, just do this:

```
git rebase -i master
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

```
git rebase -i $( git merge-base master HEAD )
```

You are fiding the point where master and your current branch diverged (or at least, one of the latest common ancestors) and using it as the parameter for rebase. That *might* work.

If what you want to know is **how many revisions** there are on your branch:

```
git log --pretty=%h $( git merge-base master HEAD ) | wc -l
```

As a side note, you could just as easily squash without doing rebase:

```
git reset --soft $( git merge-base master HEAD )
git commit -m "Squashed feature"
```

IMHO warning: I don't see why people would rather go to an editor, edit God knows how many lines when a couple of commands would do the trick. But.... anyway.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for updating my question to reflect what I was actually asking. The first command you have is what I was looking for! I am not looking at revision count. Cool side note, I guess for my case that would be a better alternative. The rebase is nice because you can choose what to do with each commit.

Comment: Oh, I understand that people would use rebase if you had a situation where you want to do something "tricky", then it makes sense.... but just squashing N revisions straight? I'd go with my recipe anytime.

Comment: "I don't see why people would rather go to an editor, edit God knows how many lines" Note that in case of the OP's situation, a search/replace equivalent to `s/pick/squash` does the trick, so editing isn't terribly time consuming.

Comment: A variant of the rebase command: `git rebase -i --onto master... master` - this uses the special syntax `A...B` to compute the merge-base.